# Error with GET method in JSON

Tags: ios, json, get

I am receiving the unauthorized BBVA APIData error. The code Im using in Xcode as Objective-C for get the data is this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.bbva.com/apidatos/zones/cards_cube.json?date_min=201301&date_max=201307&group_by=week"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization: Y2hvbWFsaS1hcHA6MGM2ZTljNjgxODNiZmUzOWY2OGJiYjY1NjZlZmU4ZTE3MzI0NTcyOQ=="];

NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *GETReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[GETReply bytes] length:[GETReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);
```

This is the documentation I used: https://developer.bbva.com/api/api-datathon/section/api-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that, in line 4, it should be

```
 [request setValue: Y2hvbWFsaS1hcHA6MGM2ZTljNjgxODNiZmUzOWY2OGJiYjY1NjZlZmU4ZTE3MzI0NTcyOQ== forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization:"];
```

You might have to remove the colon after "Authorization:"